"3 days off" not in the sense "3 days off work" but "3 days remaining"

I turned everything upside down getting ready for Christmas. I can't believe it's only 3 days off and still so much to do.

From the context, I understand 3 days off means they have 3 days remaining or they have 3 days to go before X-mas.
If I am right in my thinking, I wonder whether 3 days off is as commonly used by native speakers as the other two.

In the cited context, off (and the much more common preposition away) metaphorically equate "time remaining" with "distance remaining". Which exactly corresponds to your suggested verb-based alternative to go - being distance to travel to reach a destination (in time or space).

It means "three days away".  off is a preposition (intransitive in this construction) expressing distance-from-here or (temporal) distance-from-now or (temporal) distance from some reference timepoint.

Where are Moe and Curly?
-- Dunno. They went off together.


Election-day in the US is only a few weeks off.
It was 22 October 1929, and the stock market crash was just two days off.

I don't have any frequency statistics but it is a very common expression.
P.S. This construction is used most often with  significant upcoming occasions, either those eagerly awaited, such as Christmas or a wedding, or the opposite, something looming ahead that one is dreading.

Re "frequency statistics", my gut feel was off is not that common compared to away (or to got in OP's exact context, but not yours). So I generated this usage chart which I think makes it clear away is a safer choice for learners.

off is not a rarity so I call bullshit on that.  (There was a question recently about "calling")

 Okay, well if we tighten up on OP's specific context, by including the word Christmas, it turns out the only one that occurs enough to even chart is [with] Christmas just two days away. Like it says here, Ngrams not found: Christmas just two days off, Christmas just two days to go.

@FumbleFingers  You continually make the procedural error of relying upon ngrams when you should be looking to corpora of spoken English.   "[just, only] n [days, weeks] off" is a commonly used expression in spoken American English.  I don't know if there's any difference with BrE.   It can be used with holidays, anniversaries,  vacations, big sports games, homecomings, whatever important occasions people look forward to throughout the year.

The fact that you're familiar with off in such contexts doesn't change the fact that it's far less common than away. The difference between "common in speech" and "common in writing" isn't that extreme.

@FumbleFingers The fact that constructions like "Christmas was only three days off" are less common in printed material than away is not an indication that they are rarely used by native speakers in colloquial contexts.
